# Hive multiple insert goes wrong with the DISTINCT select statement

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I read this code from "*Hadoop the Definitive Guide*":

```
SELECT a.ad_id, a.campaign_id, a.account_id, b.user_id
FROM dim_ads a JOIN impression_logs b ON (b.ad_id = a.ad_id)
WHERE b.dateid = '2008-12-01') x
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'results_gby_adid'
SELECT x.ad_id, count(1), count(DISTINCT x.user_id) GROUP BY x.ad_id
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'results_gby_campaignid'
SELECT x.campaign_id, count(1), count(DISTINCT x.user_id) GROUP BY x.campaign_id
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'results_gby_accountid'
SELECT x.account_id, count(1), count(DISTINCT x.user_id) GROUP BY x.account_id;
```

but as my test, using several DISTINCT cannot get right results.

my hiveql as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a (logindate int, id int);
```

then
load local file to this table...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INT) PARTITIONED BY (logindate INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

then
if inserting table separately:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130120) SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM a WHERE logindate=20130120;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130121) SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM a WHERE logindate=20130121;
```

the results are correct;

but if choosing the next multiple insert hql:

```
FROM a
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130120) SELECT DISTINCT(id) WHERE logindate=20130120
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130121) SELECT DISTINCT(id) WHERE logindate=20130121;
the results are not correct, both partitions have the same number of records, seems like select from DISTINCT(id) WHERE logindate=20130120 OR logindate=20130121
```

so is it a bug or did I write some wrong syntax?

Comment: I found a workaround to finish my job: `set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nostrict
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate) SELECT DISTINCT(id),logindate FROM a DISTRIBUTE BY logindate` using the dynamic partition to init table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT has a bit of an odd history in the code as an alias to group by.
If there is a bug, then the version of hive you are using would be important to know since bugs are addressed in each release.

This might work:

```
FROM a
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130120) SELECT id WHERE logindate=20130120 GROUP BY id
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130121) SELECT id WHERE logindate=20130121 GROUP BY id;
```

if that doesn't work, this will definitely work...even though it isn't the approach you were attempting to use...

```
FROM (select distinct id, logindate from a where logindate in ('20130120','20130121')) subq_a
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130120) SELECT id WHERE logindate=20130120
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user PARTITION(logindate=20130120) SELECT id WHERE logindate=20130121;
```